# Seria posible ejecutar un script que ejecute mi servidor y, a demas, ejecutar MongoDB al mismo tiempo?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

tengo en mi proyecto de **nodejs** el siguiente `packaje.json`.

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-session": "^1.16.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.5.6",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.0"
  }
}
```

Dentro de `"scripts"` se puede ver que tengo un **comando personalizado** (`"dev"`), el cual ejecuta mi proyecto de express, luego en otra consola tendria que ejecutar el comando `mongod` para que se iniciara la base de datos de **MongoDB**,
 ¿**puedo hacer de alguna manera que mi script `dev` ejecute, ap arte de la `app.js`, el comando `mongod` y asi hacerlo todo en un solo comando llamando unicamente a : `npm run dev`**?

Comment: ¿Porqué debes iniciar el demonio de Mongo en una consola? ¿Acaso no se inicia automáticamente al arrancar el sistema operativo?

Comment: no, nunca, yo siempre que programo nodejs + angular tendgo  **3 consolas abiertas** , 1 para **angular** , otra para **node** y otra para  **mongodb**, si no nunca me cargaria las cosas que tengo en mi bd

Comment: Pero eso no me parece muy acertado. Normalmente Mongo debe arrancar con el S.O. Lo que si tiene que ejecutarse en consola es el Shell de Mongo, pero es para realizar tareas sobre la B.D. En todo caso, claro que puedes iniciar `mongod` usando un script. Ya te respondo eso dentro de poco. Saludos

Comment: Una pregunta, antes de responderte, ¿usas Windows, MacOS o Linux?

Comment: Ahora mismo : Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Como te comenté, no me parece una buena idea tener `mongod` como un servicio que inicies manualmente, suponiendo que trabajas con la última versión de Mongo.

Sin embargo, ya que lo tienes así y deseas iniciar tu servicio cada vez que ejecutes el comando `npm`, una forma de lograr lo que te propones es la siguiente:

**Sección `scripts` de `package.json`**

```
"prestart": "start \"Serivdor MongoDB\" mongod --dbpath=\"c:\\data\\db\"",
"start": "node index.js"
```

Notemos lo que sucede aqui:

1. La propiedad `prestart` es parte de los scripts soportados por `npm`, se ejecuta antes de el script `start`, por lo tanto podemos usarlo para iniciar nuestro servidor de Mongo. Hemos de notar que se ejecutará un comando `start` en una nueva ventana con el título `Servidor Mongo`, ademas, se realiza el llamado a `mongod`, lo que indica que la ruta a dicho ejecutable debe estar añadida en la variable `PATH` del sistema.
2. Luego tenemos el atributo `start` que ejecuta la llamada a `node` para levantar nuestra aplicación de Express.

Así, el comando que usaras para ejecutar tu programa debe ser:

```
npm start
```

De esta forma, `npm` buscará en la sección de `scripts` los scripts que tengas configurados, en este caso ejecutará `prestart` seguido de `start`.

Puedes leer más en la documentación de [`npm-scripts`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts).

Debemos tener en cuenta que el servicio de Mongo puede tardar en arrancar, asi que es una buena idea pasar un objeto de opciones a nuestra conexión de Mongoose para que pueda reintentar la conexión y además tenga un tiempo prudente de timeout.

Una forma de lograrlo sería:

```
const options = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  //useCreateIndex: true,
  //useFindAndModify: false,
  //autoIndex: false, // No construye índices
  reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE, // Nunca deja de intentar la conexión XD
  reconnectInterval: 500, // Reconecta cada 500 milisegundos
  poolSize: 10, // Permite hasta 10 sockets de conexión
  bufferMaxEntries: 0,
  connectTimeoutMS: 10000, // Aborta la conexión inicial después de 10 segundos
  socketTimeoutMS: 45000, // Cierra un socket después de 45 segundos de inactividad
  //family: 4 // Usa IPv4 y evita intentar el uso de IPv6
};
// Ahora la conexión la realizamos asi:
mongoose.connect(uri, options);
```

Un programa de ejemplo podría ser el siguiente:

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const mongooseConnection = mongoose.connection;
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const options = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  //useFindAndModify: false,
  //autoIndex: false, // Don't build indexes
  reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE, // Never stop trying to reconnect
  reconnectInterval: 500, // Reconnect every 500ms
  poolSize: 10, // Maintain up to 10 socket connections
  // If not connected, return errors immediately rather than waiting for reconnect
  bufferMaxEntries: 0,
  connectTimeoutMS: 10000, // Give up initial connection after 10 seconds
  socketTimeoutMS: 45000, // Close sockets after 45 seconds of inactivity
  family: 4 // Use IPv4, skip trying IPv6
};
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Iniciando aplicacion.');
  // Esperamos 5 segundos antes de intentar la conexión.
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Intentando conectar con MongoDB');
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp', options);
  }, 5000);
});

mongooseConnection.on('connected', () => {
  console.info('===> Conectado a la base de datos');
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "npm_scripts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Test for npm scripts",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "prestart": "start  \"mongoServer\" mongod --dbpath=\"c:\\data\\db\"",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "Mauricio Contreras",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "mongoose": "^5.5.6"
  }
}
```

La solución fue probada con NodeJS versión 10.3.0 y npm versión 6.1.0, en Windows 10 versión 10.0.17134.590, y MongoDB versión 4.0

Espero que esto aclare tu duda.